# API validation errors format

Tags: api, validation, error-handling

1

```
{
  "errors": {
    "firstName": ["cannot be blank", "must be 10+ characters"],
    "lastName": ["cannot contain symbols"]
  }
}
```

2

```
{
  "errors": [
    { "path": "firstName", "message": "cannot be blank" }, 
    { "path": "firstName", "message": "must be 10+ characters" },
    { "path": "lastName", "message": "cannot contain symbols" }
  ]
}
```

What format do you prefer and why, what advantages it has?

Answer (score 0):

I'd always recommend adopting an existing standard.  There's a media type `application/problem+json` which might be a good fit here.  The spec for it is here https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-http-problem-07 and is more like your second example: offering one report for each of the validation or other issues.